# Create two sub-dataframes, based on group/id, from an original dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the below dataframe:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd

#Create dataset
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2,2,2,2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
               4, 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
               5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5, 5,5,],
        'cycle': [1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
                  1,2, 3,4,5,
                  1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,
                  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
                  1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,],
        'Salary': [7, 7, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                   4, 5,6,7,8,
                   8,9,10,11,12,13,
                   8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
                   7, 7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,],
        'Children': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes',
                     'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes',
                     'Yes','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes',
                      'No',  'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',],
        'Days': [123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 96, 120,128, 66, 120,
                 15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141,
                 141,128, 66, 123, 128, 66, 120,141, 
                 123, 128, 66, 123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("df = \n", df)
```

The above dataframe looks as such:

[image]

Here, there are a total of five IDs viz. 1,2,3,4,5 as seen in 'id' column.

Now, I wish to make two separate sub-dataframes such that df1 contains id's 1,2, and 3.

And, df2 contains id's 4, and 5.

The two sub-dataframes looks as suh:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how do I achieve this task in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), `~` is for inverse mask:

```
m = df['id'].isin([1,2,3])
df1, df2 = df[m], df[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
m = df['id'].lt(4)
df1, df2 = df[m], df[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for your valuable comments. The index number of df2 starts from 22. CAn we do something and make it start from 0 ?